# Can't resize logo in responsive theme?

Tags: themes, logo, admin-css

I've been knocking my head against this one for hours. I haven't dabbled in web development in years, so I'm very rusty.

I setup a new website, clearerlines.net, designed a logo for the header, and installed it using the custom theme's(Nova Lite) options pane.

For some reason I can't yet figure out, the logo is unchangeably small. Is it due to the 'responsive' design code? Either way, is there a way around it to gain the desired effect? I'm willing to lose the responsive design in the header to gain this result, but I would like to avoid that.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is comprised of two spans which define their own width (at desktop view):

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="span3"> <!-- I have a width of 270px at desktop view -->

            <div id="logo">

               <!-- your logo here is constrained to the parent span width of 270px -->

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="span9"> <!-- I have a width of 870px at desktop view -->

            <nav id="mainmenu">

                <!-- your menu here is constrained to the parent span width of 870px -->

            </nav> 

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

You need to edit these spans accordingly and there's a couple of ways to do this:

- Your theme may provide you options in the backend dashboard that allow you to specify/modify the width of your logo area.
- If not, you should override the theme template file that contains the header markup above in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) **(recommended)**.

I would start looking at your `header.php` in your parent theme directory `nova-lite` to see whether it contains the above markup. If not, it may be included in another template file.

Once found, override it in a child theme and modify the spans to something more generous for the logo, like `span5` and `span7` for the menu. You have a total of 12 columns to work with, so divide them as you see fit.

Your theme is also using an old version of Bootstrap, version 2.3.2 for which documentation can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: Thanks for that detailed reply. I'm too much of a noob to mess with child themes - I'm more of a sysadmin than a dev. I'll try to utilize some of the details you explained to achieve my objective.